# i got 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat_id' in python telegram bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

i wrote

```
while True:

    try:
        updates = bot.get_updates()
        for update in updates:
            process_message(bot, update)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)`
```

but i got `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat_id'` error

and `process_message()` function continues without running when a message comes to the channel. I don't think there is a problem with the function.

I couldn't find a solution because I don't understand why this error is happening. I checked the `process_message()` function and there was no problem with the function but it was still getting error. When I searched why, I still couldn't come to a conclusion (I did not understand the error when I searched this forum as well).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not included the definition of the `process_message` function, I can only make an educated guess. This guess is that you're trying to access `update.message.chat_id`. Note that not all updates sent to your bot by Telegram are messages and hence `update.message` may be `None`. Please have a look at the docs of the [`Update`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.update.html#update) class (TG docs [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)) to see the different available attributes.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.